# sitecore download document when submit a form

Tags: forms, sitecore

basically I have a form for the user to submit an email, and pages with pdf documents attached to them. I'm using the sitecore fields to attach the pdf and link on the page. Basically I want to force people to submit their email if they want to download the document.

Not to sure where to start with this. I guess if there's a way to get a button as a sitecore field I could marry the two actions?

Comment: Are you using Web Forms for Marketers?

Comment: Are you talking about the module? If so no

Comment: You will need to create a .NET UserControl to add such functionality.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you here. But if you just want to make a page that requires you to submit an email before presenting you with either a download link or supplying you with the pdf directly? If that is the case, you just need to make a user control with that functionality and add it to the presentation...

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom Sitecore sublayout.

For more information have a look at section 2.3 of [Sitecore Presentation Component Reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/presentation_component_reference-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly how you are implementing it. Do you have the download links on the same page as the form?

Maybe you can do something like this - The downloads links are hidden in a panel which shows up only when a user submits his email.
So at the beginning the panel will be hidden, and if the form submission is successful then show the panel with the download links.
Hope this helps.